# Trying to get the lang option to work for Recaptcha to add I18n capability

Tags: internationalization, recaptcha, lang

I have looked at a number of forums ans posts and it seems that it has been identified in the past that the lang: 'fr' for example option does not seem to be working anymore for Recaptcha to switch the displayed locale.
I have tried a number of different potential solutions:
1. Adding javascript snippet to application.html.erb
2. Adding &h1=fr to the public key in the recaptcha_tags
3. Adding display: {theme: 'clean', lang: 'fr'} in the recaptcha_tags

and none of these have worked.
Am I just to accept that this is a bug that was introduced sometime recently into Recaptcha and has not yet been fixed?
Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am slow to respond but thanks for your help. Your info and link made me realise that I was on the right lines but had "h1" instead of "hl" - in other words I had a "one" not an "el" and had failed to spot the difference!

It's working now....

Answer (score 1):

Add the hl=fr to the query string of the challenge URL (not public key).

http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/issues/detail?id=133